# Fetching large portions of a table from Postgres with pandas and SQL alchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to fetch a large chunk (8M+) of rows from a large table (200M+ rows) from a Postgres database.

My current set up looks like this:

```
engine = create_engine(url="MY_DB_STRING",
    echo=False,
    execution_options={'stream_results': True},
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    pool_recycle=3600
)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
query = """
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE status = True
"""
dfs = []
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=session.connection(), chunksize=500000)
    df_list.append(chunk)
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
session.close()
```

The setup works with smaller dummy data but with the actual table it takes several hours. Annoyingly there is also a random chance that it can get stuck while fetching the second chunk.
How can I modify this set up to effectively and reliably fetch all 8M+ rows?

Comment: IMHO, reading the data in chunks, only to later concatenate the chunks into a large dataframe is a terrible idea because at concatenation time, you will use twice the required memory. Read in chunks if you can process data in chunks, or read it at a whole and pray for having enough memory.

Comment: With chunks my idea was to speed up execution time. Converting the data to a DataFrame as a whole will take considerably longer then converting chunks and concatenating them together. Regarding the memory, In my case I am more likely to hit the 100gb pandas limit before I ran out of actual memory on the server.

Comment: *Converting the data to a DataFrame as a whole will take considerably longer then converting chunks and concatenating them together*. Have you tried it? I am not used to handling so large data on Pandas but I would not bet a coin on that.

Comment: Also stream results has a default buffer size of 1000 which is going to not be great probably.  Do you control the postgres server and its memory as well ?

Answer (score 1):

*This isn't really a complete answer but I don't feel like putting the entire code block in a comment.*

I think you need to balance your chunk size with how you are using stream results.  There is some info about stream results and yield_per here: [streaming-with-a-fixed-buffer-via-yield-per](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#streaming-with-a-fixed-buffer-via-yield-per)  It seems that the default is 1000 which would mean you are working extra hard to fill 500,000 rows.

**WARNING: I have no idea how this will affect your postgresql server memory and/or application server memory so read the link first and consider that for yourself.**

Maybe try this after reading my warning:

```py
CHUNKSIZE=500000
dfs = []
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=session.connection().execution_options(yield_per=CHUNKSIZE), chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
    df_list.append(chunk)
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
session.close()
```